# iAd showing a white banner

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, iad

I successfully implemented an in-app purchase to remove ads in my app. It worked the first time I tried it but after I ran the app on my phone a few more times it started to just show a white ad banner instead of hidding the ad banner like it used to.

Here is the code for the StartScreen.m of my app as well as the PurchaseViewController.m to buy the IAP to remove ads. I also got a Warning saying I am using 10 instances of ADBanner even though I have them removed whenever the view disappers. Thank you for any and all help.

```
//
//StartScreen.m
//

@interface StartScreen ()
{
    BOOL _bannerIsVisible;
}
@end

@implementation StartScreen

- (void)viewDidLoad {


//Ads
    self.adBanner.delegate = self;

}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.adBanner removeFromSuperview];
    self.adBanner.delegate = nil;
    self.adBanner = nil;
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{

    // Check for Remove Ads IAP

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if ([prefs boolForKey:@"RemoveAds"] == TRUE) {
        self.adBanner.hidden = YES;
        _bannerIsVisible = NO;
    } else if (!_bannerIsVisible)
    {
        self.adBanner.hidden = NO;
        _bannerIsVisible = YES;
    }
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to retreive ad");

    // Check for Remove Ads IAP

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if ([prefs boolForKey:@"RemoveAds"] == TRUE) {
        self.adBanner.hidden = YES;
        _bannerIsVisible = NO;
    }
}

//
//  PurcahseViewController.m
//

#import "PurcahseViewController.h"

@implementation PurcahseViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.productID = @"com.app.iap1";
    [self getProductID:self];

    self.buyButton.enabled = NO;
    NSLog(@"%@", self.productID);
}

- (void)getProductID:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {
        SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:self.productID]];
        request.delegate = self;

        [request start];
    } else {
        self.productDescription.text = @"Please enable in app purchase in your settings";
    }
}

- (IBAction)purchaseItem:(id)sender {
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:self.product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}

- (IBAction)restoreButton:(id)sender {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

-(void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue {
    [self UnlockPurchase];
}

- (void)Purchased {
    NSLog(@"Item has been purchased");
}

#pragma mark _
#pragma mark SKProductsRequestDelegate

-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {

    NSArray *products = response.products;

    if (products.count != 0) {
        self.product = products[0];
        self.buyButton.enabled = YES;
        self.productTitle.text = self.product.localizedTitle;
        self.productDescription.text = self.product.localizedDescription;
    } else {
        self.productTitle.text = @"404: Product Not Found";
    }

    products = response.invalidProductIdentifiers;

    for (SKProduct *product in products) {
        NSLog(@"404: Product Not Found: %@", product);
    }
}

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {

    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased: [self UnlockPurchase];
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:NSLog(@"Transaction Failed");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                default:
                break;

        }
    }
}

-(void)UnlockPurchase {
    self.buyButton.enabled = NO;
    [self.buyButton setTitle:@"Purchased" forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs setBool:TRUE forKey:@"RemoveAds"];
    [prefs synchronize];
    [self Purchased];
}
```

Comment: Hide the banner in `didFailToReceiveAdWithError:` regardless of your "RemoveAds" conditional.

Comment: Also, the _bannerIsVisible bool is redundant.

Comment: I'll write out my comments into a proper answer so it's a bit easier for you to follow...

Answer (score 0):

First off, to answer your question, the reason your banner isn't hiding when your ad fails is because you're not hiding it. Whether or not `[prefs boolForKey:@"RemoveAds"] == TRUE`, you're going to want to hide that banner if you don't want the blank white bar in its place. To do so in the simplest possible way (without any animation), simplify your `didFailToReceiveAdWithError:` method, like so:

```
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to retreive ad");

    // Check for Remove Ads IAP
    self.adBanner.hidden = YES;
    _bannerIsVisible = NO;
}
```

And hide it in your `viewDidLoad` so it's hidden from the very beginning before any ad has loaded:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    //Ads
    self.adBanner.delegate = self;
    self.adBanner.hidden = YES;
}
```

That way, your ad will only unhide in `bannerViewDidLoadAd:` once an ad has successfully been loaded.

Secondly, your `_bannerIsVisible` boolean is unnecessary. Instead of using a separate boolean to check whether the banner is visible, you can just check whether it's hidden, with `if (self.adBanner.hidden == YES)` or `if (self.adBanner.hidden == NO)` or `if (self.adBanner.hidden)` or `if (!self.adBanner.hidden)`. Eliminating that unnecessary boolean will cut down on the potential for error.

So, just to summarize, here's my suggestion for how your `bannerViewDidLoadAd:` and `didFailToReceiveAdWithError:` methods should look:

```
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {

    // Check for Remove Ads IAP
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if ([prefs boolForKey:@"RemoveAds"] == TRUE) {
        self.adBanner.hidden = YES;
    } else if (self.adBanner.hidden) {
        self.adBanner.hidden = NO;
    }
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to retreive ad");
    self.adBanner.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: I have done just as you said and I am still getting the white iAd banner. I have tried running the app on another iPhone and once I purchase the IAP to remove ads it works fine and I have no problems with the adbanner. However, I purchased the same IAP on my original iPhone with three separate test accounts. When I go to the purchase screen it always ask me to enter the password for every test account I have bought the IAP with. It is possible that I have multiple transactions stuck in the payment queue? If this is the problem how would I go about fixing it? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: So if you don't purchase the IAP you the white iAd banner shows up? What if you add `self.adBanner.hidden = YES;` to `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: I have purchased the IAP, multiple times across three different test accounts. When I did it the first time it worked fine, when I purchased it the second time on another test account the white banners started to show up. Putting `self.adBanner.hidden = YES;` in the `viewDidLoad` does hide it but wouldn't that hide it for everyone (including those that didn't buy the IAP)?

Comment: "Putting 'self.adBanner.hidden = YES;' in the 'viewDidLoad' does hide it but wouldn't that hide it for everyone (including those that didn't buy the IAP)?" No, as long as the ad loads successfully, the banner will unhide in `bannerViewDidLoadAd:` during this part of the conditional: `else if (self.adBanner.hidden) { self.adBanner.hidden = NO; }`

Comment: Okay, is there any way I can delete the IAP I have bought so I can try this out on my devices again?

Comment: I don't know how to delete the IAP, but you could try to delete the app so it no longer has a record of your purchase.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Although now that I have added the `self.adBanner.hidden = YES;` to the `viewDidLoad` it ask me to Sign In with an Apple ID as soon as I open the app. Was there something in that the `self.adBanner.hidden = YES;` triggered to cause this?

Comment: No, definitely not. It has to be something else in your code. As your question stands, I can't help with any of the IAP stuff in your code because there's not any info as to how `PurcahseViewController` relates to the rest of your code. So I just answered your question about why the white banner was showing. As it stands, the only clear link between your `PurcahseViewController` and your `StartScreen` is the `[prefs boolForKey:@"RemoveAds"]` and that's clearly not the cause of the error. You'll have to ask a different/more relevant question to find out what's going on with that error.

Comment: Okay, I'll have to ask another question. I wasn't sure if the banner itself was the cause of this problem, which it clearly was not. Thank you very much for your help, I apperciate it immensely!